# Vim text messed up over ssh on Windows remote host regardless of terminal, works fine on Linux remote host

Tags: windows, bash, ssh, vim, mingw

`vim` works fine on the first invocation on a remote Windows host, but further use leads to my terminal getting messed up. `:redraw!` and `reset` do not help:

[image]

Using the same local terminal, `vim` works fine on a Linux remote host.

The broken remote host is a Windows server running OpenSSH, whilst the local machine is a Windows desktop. I have tried several terminal emulators, including mintty, ConEmu, and PuTTY, all have the same problem. The remote shell is bash.

I have read and tried several answers on this and other sites, including but not limited to [changing the PS1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/105974/187426), [`shopt -s checkwinsize`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/61608/187426), [`export PROMPT_COMMAND="resize &>/dev/null ; $PROMPT_COMMAND"`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/338596/187426), [`stty sane`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/522315/187426), [setting `TERM=xterm-256color`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1015368/strange-terminal-behaviour-over-ssh-from-wsl-to-ubuntu-server/1028256#1028256), [`vi -u NONE -U NONE`](https://superuser.com/a/1136545/1133364), [`:set wrap`/`:set nowrap`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/425272/187426), [`export set LINES=58`](https://superuser.com/a/1179590/1133364)... Nothing worked so far.

Relevant info (of the remote host):

```
afarah@BackRowL06 MINGW64 ~
$ uname -a
MINGW64_NT-10.0-14393 BackRowL06 3.0.7-338.x86_64 2019-11-21 23:07 UTC x86_64 Msys


afarah@BackRowL06 MINGW64 ~
$ echo $SHELL
/c/program files/git/bin/bash.exe

afarah@BackRowL06 MINGW64 ~
$ cat ~/.profile

afarah@BackRowL06 MINGW64 ~
$

afarah@BackRowL06 MINGW64 ~
$ echo $TERM
xterm

afarah@BackRowL06 MINGW64 ~
$ vim --version | grep terminfo
-balloon_eval      +folding           +multi_byte        +terminfo

afarah@BackRowL06 MINGW64 ~
$ stty -a
speed 38400 baud; rows 24; columns 80; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>;
eol2 = <undef>; swtch = ^Z; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R;
werase = ^W; lnext = ^V; discard = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
-parenb -parodd cs8 -hupcl -cstopb cread -clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr icrnl ixon -ixoff
-iuclc -ixany -imaxbel iutf8
opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
isig icanon iexten echo -echoe -echok -echonl -noflsh -tostop -echoctl -echoke
-flusho

afarah@BackRowL06 MINGW64 ~
$ cat ~/.vimrc
cat: /c/Users/afarah/.vimrc: No such file or directory

afarah@BackRowL06 MINGW64 ~
$ bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.4.23(1)-release (x86_64-pc-msys)
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

I am pretty sure it is a problem with my remote host, as I use the same terminals on this Windows machine to `ssh` to my Linux server and `vi` works fine, but I cannot figure out the issue. Here are the same info from my Linux server:

```
marius:~ uname -a
Linux marius 4.19.0-6-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.67-2+deb10u1 (2019-09-20) x86_64 GNU/Linux

marius:~ echo $SHELL
/usr/bin/zsh

marius:~ echo $TERM
xterm

marius:~ vim --version | grep terminfo
-balloon_eval      +folding           +multi_byte        +terminfo

marius:~ stty -a
speed 38400 baud; rows 24; columns 80; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = M-^?; eol2 = M-^?;
swtch = <undef>; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R; werase = ^W;
lnext = ^V; discard = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
-parenb -parodd -cmspar cs8 -hupcl -cstopb cread -clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk -brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr icrnl ixon -ixoff
-iuclc ixany imaxbel iutf8
opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
isig icanon iexten echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt
echoctl echoke -flusho -extproc
```

I tried updating the remote host shell and vim (both come with git-bash, which I installed there), to no avail. The output above is from the already updated host, using the latest version from https://git-scm.com/. The gif is from a previous version of vim.

PS: The same terminals in which `vim` fail remotely work when ran locally on the remote server (accessed through Window's remote desktop).

Comment: If the server is running Windows 10 and you are not using the built-in SSH server of Windows, try enabling it in *Settings > Apps > Apps & features > Optional features > Add a feature*, select "OpenSSH Server" and click on the *Install* button.

Comment: Does running `infocmp xterm` on the remote system produce a terminfo definition or an error message?  Also, what does `vim --version | grep builtin_terms` produce on the remote system?

Comment: @bk2204 `infocmp` does not produce an error message: [output](https://pastebin.com/raw/9p1EwhTr). `vim --version | grep builtin_terms` produces ` ++builtin_terms    -hangul_input      +packages          +timers`.

Comment: [Setting TERM to cygwin](https://superuser.com/a/767736/1133364) finally did the trick.

Comment: (only on PuTTY)